# git add auto-complete filename

Tags: git, zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I am working on a git project.
Since I have a lot of folder deepness, I would like to improve my auto-completion to work with filenames and not only paths.

Here is an example:

```
$git status                                                                                                                        1 ↵  ✹master 
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/src/main/java/fr/pasteque/client/BaseFlavor.java
    modified:   app/src/main/java/fr/pasteque/client/widgets/RestaurantTicketsAdapter.java

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I obviously have to add a file with:

`git add app/src/main/java/fr/pasteque/client/BaseFlavor.java`

But I would love to be able to write: `git add BaseFlavor.java`

`git add **/BaseFlavor.java` works!

But the completion, like `git add **/Base<tab>`, doesn't..

Any ideas how it can works with completion ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Try `git add **/Base*<tab>` (notice the additional `*`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works but complete with all the files with 'Base*'. I want zsh to only complete with the addable files. In this case it should only complete with BaseFlavor.java

Comment: Wow. How could I live without this for all these years… Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not an exact answer to the question, but there is a very handy tool from Facebook - [PathPicker](https://github.com/facebook/pathpicker/) - you can just select modified files you want to add.

Comment: Unfortunately, not supported on Windows (but will probably work with WSL).

Answer (score 0):

This is very handy bash script which could help you: http://code-worrier.com/blog/autocomplete-git/

You can't use `git add **/filename*` but `git add <tab>` offers you just files and paths which are ready to commit, untracked, merge conflicts etc ..

**Edit from 10.3.2020**
bash script source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

then just edit your `.bashrc` as follows

```
if [ -f ~/pathto/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/pathto/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

Comment: Link is broken :(

Comment: Hi Mosh. Sorry to hear that. I have updated the answer. I hope it helps.